# Problems implementing zoom/pan and translate events using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having problems implementing zoom events after transformation events.

The basic setup consists of:

```
var graphSvg = d3.select("#graphDiv").append("svg")
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([0.1, 4])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);
graphSvg.call(zoom);
var graphG = graphSvg.append("g");

function zoomed() {
  graphG.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

Now the problem is when some event causes a transformation eg:

```
graphG
  .attr("transform", "translate(200,200) scale(1)");
```

This works fine... but when I start to pan it snaps back and starts from the original position before the transform event

Am I missing some additional steps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I closed as duplicat but wanted to add a little more detail, so I created a quick **more generic** example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qNe2A5lHZhbqnqiCj6cx?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark this answers my question perfectly! :)